# Merge similar arrays on values where they have minor differences

Tags: php, array-merge

I have an array that contains the parts of a word like this:

ORIGINAL

```
Array
(
    [1001002.0480] => A
    [1001002.0490] => l
    [1001002.0500] => f
    [1001002.0510] => a
    [1001002.0520] => b
    [1001002.0530] => e
    [1001002.0540] => t
)
```

So after some processing I end up with an array like this...:

PROCESSED

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => l
    [2] => p
    [3] => h
    [4] => a
    [5] => b
    [6] => e
    [7] => ´
    [8] => t
)
```

...which I need to merge with the first one to get the address numbers as the keys and then generate some new address numbers for those symbols which don't have address numbers.

FINAL

```
Array
(
    [1001002.0480] => A
    [1001002.0490] => l
    [1001002.0500] => p
    [1001002.0505] => h
    [1001002.0510] => a
    [1001002.0520] => b
    [1001002.0530] => e
    [1001002.0535] => ´
    [1001002.0540] => t
)
```

Note: Don't worry too much about generating the address/keys, I am really just looking for a reliable way to merge the values while keeping the keys of the first array. I can then process the array afterwards to fix any new keys which don't match the address system.

Comment: A dirty simple way would be to just loop through your second array, check if the value exists in the first array with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and if not, then add it to the end of the arary, either with `array_push();` or a simple `$array[<KEY>] = <VALUE>` - Or [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)